# stopping VBScript exec from flashing on screen

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I have a simple VBScript which writes stdOutput to a textfile using a loop.

The script works, however my problem is that a flashing a window appears on the screen each time the loop runs. I wish to stop that flashing window from appearing.

I am runnning the vbscript via windows `cmd.exe`.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim counter, myNum, fileLine, outFile, objFile 
myNum = 0
counter = 90

outFile = "netband_logger_vbs.tmp"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)

Do While myNum < counter
    myNum = myNum + 1
    Call GetConnections()
Loop

Function GetConnections()
    i = 0
    Set shExec = sh.Exec("netstat -e")
    Do While Not shExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        fileLine = shExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
        objFile.Write fileLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    objFile.Close
End Function
```

Comment: have you tried using Run instead of exec?

Comment: am a total noob on this have no idea how Run IS USED.

Comment: `Run` was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46739982/1682881) in an answer to your previous question.

Comment: If you don't read the answers people already gave you, can you at least [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx)?